# Showing that a double sum is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, summation

Suppose $a,b \in l^2(\mathbb{N})$.  Show that there exists $C$ such that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_n b_k}{n+k} \leq C\  ||a||\  ||b||  $$

My (incorrect) attempt: I thought of using a double cauchy-schwarz argument. We can factor the $a_n$ out of the inner sum (duh):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_n b_k}{n+k} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{b_k}{n+k} $$

Now applying Cauchy-Schwartz to the inner sum first:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_k}{n+k} \leq \bigg( \sum_k |b_k|^2 \bigg)^{1/2} \bigg(\sum_k \frac{1}{(n+k)^2} \bigg)^{1/2} = ||b|| \bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+k)^2} \bigg)^{1/2}  = c_n$$

Then we can apply it again:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{b_k}{n+k} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nc_n \leq  \bigg( \sum_n |a_n|^2 \bigg)^{1/2} \bigg( \sum_n |c_n|^2 \bigg)^{1/2}$$

$$\leq ||a||\  ||b|| \bigg( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+k)^2}\bigg)^{1/2} $$

The problem is that the double sum in the last line does not converge. In fact,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+k)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)^2}  $$

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Dan. What happens if you replace $n+k \ge 2√n√k$, AM-GM, then use CS?

Comment: You can find Schur's proof of Hilbert's inequality at page 113 of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view)

Comment: You want $|a_nb_k|$ in your first equation.